# Hive/Pig - Column to Row Conversion

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hiveql

**Input Data**

```
**Col1| Col2 | Col3 | Col4**

 2  | 500 | 50 | 100
```

How to convert columns to rows in hive or pig ?

**Expected Output:**

```
**Column  | Value**

Col1  |   2

Col2  | 500

Col3  | 50

Col4  | 100
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for UNPIVOT.

```
SELECT 'Col1' as 'Column' ,Col1  AS Value FROM htable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col2' as 'Column' ,Col3  AS Value FROM htable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col3' as 'Column' ,Col3  AS Value FROM htable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Col4' as 'Column' ,Col4  AS Value FROM htable
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT col1
    ,col2
FROM (
    SELECT MAP('Col1', Col1, 'Col2', Col2, 'Col3', Col3, 'Col4', Col1) AS tmp
    FROM mytable
    ) mytab LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(mytab.tmp) explode_tmp AS col1
    ,col2